# Converting a USB C into a Y-split USB A for chaging

Tags: usb, usb-c, split

I'm looking to split a USB-C (female) into two USB-A (female as well), strictly for charging.

Would it by any chance be possible for me to solder the four voltage connector pins   from the USB-c to the voltage pins on the USB-a, and then do the same for ground?

I'm looking at something like below:

[image]

That would be glued tight into a 3d printed enclosure

Comment: A small PCB would be the best solution. USB C connector's PCB pins are fragile.

Comment: @LiorBilia I've added some more information to the post, however could you maybe suggest one? :)

Comment: I hope you don't intend to charge your phone and your laptop at the same time.

Comment: @Jasen, I'm not looking for power delivery. I got these bike lights that each charge via USB-A, which is a bit inconvenient since you typically have to charge them at the same time. I wanted to create an enclosure, where I could charge them both preferably with USB-c

Comment: Get a charger with two Type-A outputs and don't confuse Type-C hosts and users of your splitter.

Comment: @Jazerix This is actually a tricky design, you may want to dive into how USB charging works. To start with, only one side of the USB Type-C 2.0 lines host charger will be effectively connected to one of the Type-A and only the device on that A port will know the charger specs. When you'll connect the second device on the second port, it will may or may not start to draw current. If it does, the combination of the 2 devices may exceed what the charger can deliver because the second device has no idea what the current limit of the charger is and how much current the first device is sinking.

Answer (score 1):

What's the goal here?  If you need to charge a couple USB-A devices then there's far easier ways to do this for not a lot of money.  There's lots of dual port USB-A chargers out there, I found one without much trouble.
https://shop.aukey.com/products/12w-dual-port-usb-wall-charger

If you have to start with USB-C for power there's inexpensive options there too.
[https://www.amazon.com/Pengo-Adapter-Transfer-Plug-N-Play-Silver/dp/B07BFQMCVK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BFQMCVK)

If the power draw from the two ports is less than 5 watts each then it shouldn't be too hard to dig into the USB spec to make each port play like it's an old school (pre-USB-PD) power brick, and have the USB-C side go into a similar "dumb" mode to look like a 10 or 12 watt device to a USB-C power brick.

With the old USB power bricks they would report their power output capability by having a specified resistance across the data pins, at least as I recall.  USB-C ports on devices support this for backward compatibility.  Depending on how much power this is supposed to handle, and how concerned you are on making this safe from overloading something, this could be trivial to more trouble than it's worth.